# Assertion Error:?

Tags: python

I have written this function but i keep getting assertion error and i don't know why???

```
  def amino(codonfile, DNA):
        """This function reads the 64-line codon file and then converts the DNA string entered into an amino acid string."""
        codonfile = []
        for line in codonfile:
            x,y = line.split()
            if DNA == dict[x]:
                return dict[y]
    codonfile = open("codon.txt","r")   
    codonfile.close

    assert(amino("codon.txt","TTT")== "Phe")
    assert(amino("codon.txt","TTATTCTTGTCT")== "LeuPheLeuSer")
    assert(amino("codon.txt","TTAGGGCCCTAC")== "LueGlyProTyr")
    print("passed")
```

Comment: obviously because one of your 3 assertions is failing ....

Comment: Show us the traceback so we can help you debug this. You can add a assertion text (`assert(expression, "some assertion identifying text here")`) to help ease debugging.

Comment: +1 2 Joran Beasley ) Show the stack trace.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assert

read up on assertions and what they do.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is patent nonsense, and will always return `None`.

You are ignoring the opened file, pass in a filename to your function, then replace *that* with an empty list, so you end up looping over that empty list and not producing any results.

In the end, each of your `assert` statements compares the result (`None`) to a string, which will never match and thus fail.

Comment: and `codonfile.close` isn't really helping

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are trying to solve the same problem as listed in [your prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237253/read-file-into-dictionary).  Good job including your code this time.

Here are some problems with your code.

```
def amino(codonfile, DNA):
    """This function reads the 64-line codon file and then converts the DNA string entered into an amino acid string."""
    codonfile = []
    for line in codonfile:
```

`codonfile` is provided as an argument to `amino`, but you immediately overwrite it with an empty list!  Since `codonfile` is an empty list there is nothing to iterate over.  Your for-loop loops zero times.  Instead do this:

```
def amino(codonfile, DNA):
    with open(codonfile, 'r') as f:  # opens the file and assigns to f
        for line in f:
```

Now, the inside of your for-loop is also quite messed up.

```
    for line in codonfile:
        x,y = line.split()
        if DNA == dict[x]:
            return dict[y]
```

There is no dictionary named `dict` at this point.  (But there is a builtin-in `dict` type so don't use that name).  Instead you need to *fill* a dictionary with the items in `codonfile`.  Prior to your for-loop you need to create a dictionary to hold those items.  Do it like this:

```
codon_table = {} # brackets for an empty dictionary
for line in f:
    x, y = line.split()
    codon_table[x] = y
```

The final bit is to use the `codon_table` to translate the DNA string.  You'll need to chunk `DNA` into 3 letter pieces and get a translation from the `codon_table`.  Then you'll need to join those translations into a single string and return it.

I left that final paragraph unimplemented as an exercise.  Give it a shot and if you can't get it post what you have tried as another question.

Comment: +1, *this* is the way to answer a (probable) homework question!